# Why Int, Double and Nothing 's common super type is AnyVal

Tags: scala, types, inference

```
scala> def b(x:Int) = { x match { case 1 => 1; case 2 => 3.5; case k => throw new Exception("Nothing")}} 
b: (x: Int)AnyVal
scala> def c(x: Int) = if (x == 1) 1 else if (x == 2) 3.5 else throw new Exception("Nothing")
c: (x: Int)Double
```

This is what I got from REPL. Why does scala compiler treat function `b`' s return type as `AnyVal`. As I think, it should be `Double`.
Any pointing will be helpful.

Comment: `Double` is not a supertype of `Int` - the most specific common supertype between them is `AnyVal`.

Comment: @Lee this is true, but `Int` is usually implicitly converted to `Double`. It is the presence of third `case` that throws the type-inference off in this case.

Comment: @Dima, Thanks for you help! I still wonder why `throws` clause stops the implicit convert `Int` to `Double`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can declare it as `def b(x:Int): Double` if you need it to be treated that way. 
Without it, the compiler gets confused by the `throws` clause and infers the type incorrectly. Type inference isn't perfect, sometimes you have to help the magic :)

Answer (score 4):

`Nothing` is a subtype of *every* type (see [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing)). This is necessary to allow expressions such as

```
val x : Int = ???
```

The least common supertype of `Int` and `Double` is `AnyVal`. `Nothing`, being a subtype of anything (including `AnyVal`), hence does not change the inferred type.

Comment: This is technically correct, but a bit misleading: while the common supertype of Int and Double is indeed AnyVal, the reason for failed type inference is the third `case` with the `throw` clause. Without it, the `Int` is implicitly converted to `Double`, and `Double` return type is inferred correctly. Curiously, replacing `3.5` with `3` also changes the inferred type to `Int`.

Comment: That last is not at all surprising - of course the common supertype of `Int`, `Int` and `Nothing` is `Int`.

Comment: @misberner Sorry for that I didn't state my question clearly. When the third case is removed, the type-inference could inferred the return type as `Double`

Comment: @Dima I fail to see how inferring AnyVal as the least common supertype of Int and Double as a failure, seems completely correct to me.

Comment: @stew I think we can't tell it fails or not if we don't see the context that defines this function. Please see function `c`? It inferred as `Double`

Comment: @stew, the thing is that removing the third `case` (or replacing it with, say, `0L`), as well as changing the first case to `Double`, makes the inferred type change to `Double`. Obviously, throwing an exception in some cases should not affect the function's return type. If this is not convincing enough, consider removing the third `case` completely, which will result in the same exact behavior (except for the type of actual exception), but will infer `Double` as return type. This is my rational for calling this a failure. I stand by my words.